# Regex capture different type of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture data from input like:

```
...
10   79    QUANT. DE ITENS A FORNECER       O    N     9    0   67  75
           E' a quantidade  de  itens  que o fornecedor consegue suprir
           o cliente para uma determinada data. As casa decimais estao 
           definidas no campo 022 (unid. casas decimais).              

11   24    DATA ENTREGA/EMBARQUE DO ITEM    O    N     6    0   76  81
           Data de entrega/embarque do item. Nos casos em que este cam-
           po nao contiver a data, seu conteudo devera ser ajustado en-
           tre as partes. 
...
```

My goal is to capture:
('10',   '79',    'QUANT. DE ITENS A FORNECER', 'O','N', '9', '0', '67', 75') and so on...

My first try was to loop over line and capture as follow:

```
def parse_line(line):
    pattern = r"\s(\d{1,6}|\w{1})\s" # do not capture the description
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        tab_find = re.findall(pattern, line, re.DOTALL|re.UNICODE)
        if len(tab_find) > 6:
            return tab_find
```

My Second try was to split the text and append expected result:

```
def ugly_parsing(line):
    result = [None] * 9 # init list
    tab_r = list(filter(None, re.split(r"\s", line))) # ignore '' 
    keys = [0, 1, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]
    for i in keys:
        result[i] = tab_r[i]
    result[2] = " ".join(tab_r[2:-6])
    return result
```

Ignoring the description is OK, but when the description contains a single letter my regex it not working.

Comment: Why don't you split on more than one space, i.e. `r'\s{2,}'`? Or are they tabs?

Comment: Please precise what output you need. It is not clear (*and so on*).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, good alternative !

Comment: Whoever made that file has obviously never parsed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just translate that line into a regex, with all the required numbers and characters, and give whatever remains to the description. You can do this using a non-greedy match: `(.+?)`.

```
p = re.compile(r"^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)$")
for line in text.splitlines():
    m = p.match(line)
    if m:
        print m.groups()
```

Output is

```
('10', '79', 'QUANT. DE ITENS A FORNECER', 'O', 'N', '9', '0', '67', '75')
('11', '24', 'DATA ENTREGA/EMBARQUE DO ITEM', 'O', 'N', '6', '0', '76', '81')
```

Not sure whether that makes it more readable, but you could also construct that large regex from smaller parts, e.g. `"^" + r"(\d+)\s+" * 2 + "(.+?)" + r"\s+(\w+)" * 6 + "$"` or `"^" + "\s+".join([r"(\d+)"] * 2 + ["(.+?)"] + [r"(\w+)"] * 6) + "$"`

Or, depending or your input, you could split by other things than single spaces, such as two-or-more spaces `\s{2,}` (as suggested in comments) or tabs, but this could yield problems in case the description contains those, too. Using a fixed number of stuff "around" the description might be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! My input is a file containing many such text block. I will loop over all lines to be able to add checks.

Answer (score 1):

Given a file like so:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt
10   79    QUANT. DE ITENS A FORNECER       O    N     9    0   67  75
           E' a quantidade  de  itens  que o fornecedor consegue suprir
           o cliente para uma determinada data. As casa decimais estao 
           definidas no campo 022 (unid. casas decimais).              

11   24    DATA ENTREGA/EMBARQUE DO ITEM    O    N     6    0   76  81
           Data de entrega/embarque do item. Nos casos em que este cam-
           po nao contiver a data, seu conteudo devera ser ajustado en-
           tre as partes.
```

If you want to capture the description, you can use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) with a regex and capture the file block by block.

Example:

```
import re
import mmap
block_pattern=re.compile(r'^(\d+\s+\d+\s+.*?)(?=(?:^\s*$)|\Z)', flags=re.S | re.M)
data_pattern=re.compile(r'^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\w)\s+(\w)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$')
with open(fn) as f:
    txt=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for block in block_pattern.finditer(txt):
        block_lines=block.group(0).partition('\n')
        m=data_pattern.search(block_lines[0])
        if m:
            block_data=[m.groups(), block_lines[2]]
            print block_data
```

Prints:

```
[('10', '79', 'QUANT. DE ITENS A FORNECER', 'O', 'N', '9', '0', '67', '75'), "           \x0fE' a quantidade  de  itens  que o fornecedor consegue suprir\n           \x0fo cliente para uma determinada data. As casa decimais estao \n           \x0fdefinidas no campo 022 (unid. casas decimais).              \n"]
[('11', '24', 'DATA ENTREGA/EMBARQUE DO ITEM', 'O', 'N', '6', '0', '76', '81'), '           \x0fData de entrega/embarque do item. Nos casos em que este cam-\n           \x0fpo nao contiver a data, seu conteudo devera ser ajustado en-\n           \x0ftre as partes. \n']
```

---

As stated in comments, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/qO9gH7/1) is very close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Due to the way i'm looping through the file, the use of mmap.mmap should be refined. Do you think that be possible to capture all blocks of a file as describe below ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you.

The goal of the script is to parse the txt file [link][1]

[1]: http://www.anfavea.com.br/rnd/006.TXT RND definition file to python structure as:

```
    recorddefs = [{'ITP': [['1', '1', 'IDENT. REGISTRATION TYPE', 'M', 'A', '3', '0', '1', '3'],
                   ['2', '33', 'IDENTIFICATION OF THE PROCESS', 'M', 'N', '3', '0', '4', '6'],
                           ...]},
          'RP1': [['1', '1', 'IDENT. REGISTRATION TYPE', 'M', 'A', '3', '0', '1', '3'],
                  ['2', '2', 'COD. DESTINATION FACTORY', 'M', 'A', '3', '0', '4', '6'],
...]},
          'RP2': [['1', '1', 'IDENT. REGISTRATION TYPE', 'M', 'A', '3', '0', '1', '3'],
                  ['2', '24', 'DATA DELIVERY / SHIPMENT OF THE ITEM', 'M', 'N', '6', '0', '4', '9'],
                  ['3', '25', 'QT DELIVERY / SHIPMENT OF THE ITEM', 'M', 'N', '9', '0', '10', '18'],
...,]}]
```

Each block is identified by a code (3 digits) with the description for all elements belonging to it (block == segment).

For now my (just snippet) code looks like:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    with contextlib.suppress(StopIteration):
        with open(filename) as fin:
            while True:
                line = next(fin)
                if "LAYOUT DE REGISTRO" in line:
                    yield parse_segment_block(fin)


def parse_segment_block(fin_iter):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    k = None
    while True:
        line = next(fin_iter)
        if re.search(r"\s(\w{3})\s", line) and not k:
            k = re.search(r"\s(\w{3})\s", line).group(1)
        tab_parser = parse_line(line)
        if tab_parser:
            r[k].append(tab_parser)
        if "Rede Nacional de Dados" in line:
            return r


def parse_line(line):
    line = line.strip()
    p = re.compile(r"^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)$")
    m = p.match(line.strip())
    if m:
        result = list(m.groups())
        result[2] = translate(result[2]) # google translate call
        return result
```

Considering the above response. According to @dawn's response,is it possible to have global search pattern ?

Comment: Is this a new/follow-up question? If so, you should post it as another question (maybe with a reference to this question), but not as an answer.

Comment: My fault. I didn't post the comment. The answer is just for illustrate it.

Comment: BTW, why don't you use a `for` loop instead of `while True`, `next`, and suppressing `StopIteration`?

Comment: A simplification of coroutine use. The main idea was delegate the block parsing to a smaller task.